# Standard notation for conjugacy class

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, soft-question, notation

For a group $G$, we are all familiar with the notion of the conjugacy class of an element $s \in G$, being the set of conjugates of $s$ in $G$, $\textit{i.e.}:$

$$\{t^{-1}st \mid t \in G \}.$$

I have seen the conjugacy class of an element $s \in G$ variously denoted by $\textit{e.g.}$ $c(s)$, $\textrm{Cl}(s)$, etc.

Is there a more or less universally acknowledged correct standard notation, as one might expect there to be for such a basic and prevalent mathematical object?

Comment: I think, not. You maybe also have $C_s$, $\mathcal{O}_s$, even ${}^G s$, etc.

Comment: In geometric group theory it is common to use $[s]$.

Comment: Mathematicians are anarchists and they don't believe in correct standard notations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It varies with the context. In an abstract setting (such as a proof) for the conjugacy class of $s \in G$ you generally write $s^G$ or $\;^Gs$, $\operatorname{Cl}(s)$, or $C_s$, $C(s)$, and more. Watch out for confusion with the centraliser of $s$, denoted as $C_G(s)$ (you do see both objects together sometimes, as they are involved in the class equation).

Moreover, when you are interested in studying conjugacy classes in general (for example when you compute a character table) you denote them as "$nL$"  where $n$ is the order of the elements in it and $L$ is a letter. So for example if you had two conjugacy classes of elements with order $2$ you would call them $2A, 2B$.

Sometimes you know more, and you employ a more explicit notation. The classic example is the one of symmetric groups: conjugacy classes are determined by the cycle structure, so you denote them with it instead: for the classes of $S_4$ you would write $(1), (2), (2)(2), (3)$ and $(4)$

Comment: perfectly good answer (+1) but for the sake of my undergrad students I would warn against using $C(s)$ for conjugacy class as I have seen it used for centraliser which can lead to some very confusing calculations!

Comment: I did warn against that! Sadly, I have seen $C(s)$ in some textbooks...

Comment: I would warn against using $C_s$ for conjugacy class because it often denotes the cyclic group of order $s$. Also when you use $\mathrm{Cl}(s)$, it may be a good idea to write $\mathrm{Cl}_G(s)$ to specify _where_ you consider; this is usually obvious from the context but sometimes very confusing, especially your argument involves several subgroups.

Comment: @Orat in this context $s$ denotes a group element, so it should be clear (at least!) whether $s$ is an integer or not. I agree about your second point, but only when it makes sense to specify (i.e. when it is not obvious).

Comment: My concern is about extreme (but elementary) cases like $G = \mathbf{Z}$ or $\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z}$; or a variable $s$ is used (accidentally) for several meanings. Without careful proofreading, an unintended conflict occurs; this is usually not harmful, but ugly. Anyway, take some time to choose good symbols is always a good idea.